# How to assign a value to variable using Sql String

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, dynamic-sql

I would like to assign a select value to a variable using sql string. Below is my code:

```
DECLARE @maxRow INT, @tableName NVARCHAR(128) = N'whatever';

select @maxRow=Max(id) from @tableName
```

But this throws an error:

> Msg 1087, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   
> Must declare the table variable "@tableName".

Even though I did declare the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a variable for a table name unless you put it into dynamic SQL. The code is currently expecting `@tableName` to be a table variable, not a string, though it's clear from your syntax this is not what you intended. This usage smells like sub-optimal design and lends itself to significant SQL injection risks, but you can try this code instead:

```
DECLARE @maxRow INT;

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT @maxRow = MAX(id) FROM ' 
  + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + ';';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@maxRow INT OUTPUT', @maxRow OUTPUT;

PRINT @maxRow;
```

Please do read up on SQL injection and normalization.